# Sanctum - can't shoot strawberry fish

Tags: steam, achievements, sanctum

In sanctum (for steam), there's three achievements related to shooting [strawberry fish](http://sanctum.wikia.com/wiki/Strawberry_Fish), but no matter how much I shoot them, or what game mode, I never get any progress towards any of the achievements. Is there a known bug or glitch related to these achievements, and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen on http://steamcommunity.com/stats/Sanctum/achievements, Steam updated the names of the achievements to include (not working) beside those achievements, as well as a couple others. It seems that a recent update to the way bullets hits are handled broke them, and they plan to fix it in the next update (whenever that is).

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as this was asked in November 2011, I would just like to update this question with the fact that they now can be shot.

1. Find the fish during the build phase, so that you have all the time
   in the world.
2. Start the wave, switch to your own weapon of choice (I use the
   sniper)
3. Shoot the fish in it's cute, smiling, innocent face, you monster

When the fish are hit they make little cries, if you didn't hear a cry then you might have missed, shot again till you hear the cry and progress in the achievement.